# How to find list of enterprise applications which an AD group can access

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, terraform, azure-cli, active-directory-group

Is there a way through which we can find the list of Enterprise Applications which an AD group can access?

I see the option in the Azure Portal which lets me see this, but there's no AzCLI or Terraform module which can list this down.

[Picture for reference in the Azure Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mK6Um.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a command in PowerShell for reference - would still await for any alternatives if possible.

Get-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId `<objectId>`. ObjectID can be found from the Group in Azure AD, or we can use the following to get the data:

```
$GroupId = Get-AzureADMSGroup -SearchString "<groupName>" | Select-Object Id -ExpandProperty Id
Get-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $GroupId
```

Requires **Install-Module AzureAD** and **Connect-AzureAD** to be executed before running this.

Comment: @DelliganeshS-MT I will be able to do the same tomorrow